# What does "weather forecasts" mean?

Tags: c#, razor-pages

When I study the [RazorPage documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-razor-pages-aspnet-core/3-exercise-create-new-aspnetcore-app), I read the paragraph below:

> In the terminal window, copy and paste the following command
>
> `dotnet new webapp -f net6.0`
>
> This command creates the files for a basic web
> API project, along with a C# project file named RazorPagesPizza.csproj
> that will return a list of ***weather forecasts***.

So what does "weather forecasts" really refer to?

Comment: Suspect it is incorrect documentation. Previous Razor samples were for a weather forecast sample, not a Pizza sample

Comment: Cloudy with a chance of meatballs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's a typo/copypasta error on the part of the person who wrote the docs, importing content from documentation about a different different kind of project.

Quite a few of the Microsoft example app templates use a weather forecast to demonstrate data that might be shuttled between client and server. For example if you do `dotnet new blazorserver -f net6.0` you'll end up with a Blazor Server app that has a `WeatherForecast.cs` and related service in its Data directory

> So what does "weather forecasts" really refer to?

In the `webapp` template; nothing - the code doesn't really do much other than display a nav menu sidebar and index page.

If you're looking to get into web dev you might want to skip the ASP.NET webapp one, because it's fairly old tech now. The modern web development trend is for a javascript application that runs in the browser, fetches small amounts of data from a back end API and manipulates the active html document to make it look like things are happening, rather than sending massive blocks of HTML between server and client and having the browser replace the active page with another one (which is what this one does).

If javascript doesn't float your boat, take a look at Blazor; it effectively works like the javascript-plus-light-communication-with-backend I mentioned, but it lets you write all your page changes with C# alone. In a Blazor server app the server maintains knowledge of the HTML the client needs and sends small chunks of it which are patched into the active document. In a Blazor Web App a small .net runtime is sent to the client so the C# runs in the browser and formulates the HTML that is patched into the document the user sees

Comment: No problem! If this answers your question you can click the grey check mark to turn it green. This changes the appearance of the  question on the dashboard to let people know you're no longer looking for an answer